# JavaScript inside HTML on order of execution

Tags: javascript, html

The following code displays AAA, BBB, CCC, EEE, FFF. It skips DDD.
Could someone help why DDD is skipped. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      func1('AAA');
      function func1(x) { alert(x); }
      func1('BBB');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      func2('CCC');
    </script>
    <script>
      function func2(x) { alert(x); }
    </script>
    <script>
      func2('DDD');
    </script>
    <script>
      func3('EEE');
      function func3(x) { alert(x); }
      func3('FFF');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its actually `CCC` which is not showing since the `func2` is not yet defined, not sure what are you seeing on your end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It "skips" CCC, not DDD. And the reason is shown in your browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: func2 is not defined
```

Function declarations are only hoisted to the top of the script they're in, browsers don't load all scripts, do hoisting, and *then* run the step-by-step code.

So as of the

```
<script>
  func2('CCC');
</script>
```

...there is no `func2`, and that fails. (Later, of course, `func2` is added, and so `func2('DDD')` works and we see DDD.)

Comment: that leads me to my question on the head section, why `AAA` was called? since `func1` is not yet defined too?

Comment: That's right, my mistake, CCC is skipped. So, is it because each func2 call is in a separate script tag?

Comment: @Roljhon It's defined in the same script block. When it's called it's already loaded. If you change the example to the same situation as `func2` you see the same hoisting issue: `<script>
            func1('AAA');
            </script><script>
            function func1(x) {console.log(x);}
            func1('BBB');
        </script>`

Comment: @Roljhon: What scrappedcola said. In the answer, it's "Function declarations are only hoisted to the top of the script they're in." `func1` is in the same script `func1('AAA')` is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes got it, not familiar with the word, sorry :) thanks!

Comment: @Roljhon: Fair enough! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You mean skip the `CCC` not the `DDD` that totally logic since you're trying to call a function before it's definition `func2`, so if you check your console you could see the error message that describe this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: func2 is not defined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            func1('AAA');
            function func1(x) {alert(x);}
            func1('BBB');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            func2('CCC');
        </script>
        <script>
            function func2(x) {alert(x);}
        </script>
        <script>
            func2('DDD');
        </script>

        <script>
            func3('EEE');
            function func3(x) {alert(x);}
            func3('FFF');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead if you put the definition of `func2` in the same `script` with the call that will hoists the actual function definition and it'll work just fine as `func1` did.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            func1('AAA');
            function func1(x) {alert(x);}
            func1('BBB');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            func2('CCC');
            function func2(x) {alert(x);}
        </script>
        <script>
            func2('DDD');
        </script>

        <script>
            func3('EEE');
            function func3(x) {alert(x);}
            func3('FFF');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Grammar issues aside, without a mention of function hoisting this answer is incomplete at best.

Comment: Being "correct" doesn't make an answer good. Helping the asker understand the problem completely—which in this case cannot be done without mention of function hoisting ("you're trying to call a function before it's [sic] definition" isn't very helpful when in OP's code `func1` is *also* called before its definition but works fine)—makes an answer good.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @Jordan .. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I do not understand why CCC run if the method is not declared over the line use. the correct declaration is this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function func1(x) {alert(x);}
        func1('AAA');
        func1('BBB');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function func2(x) {alert(x);}
    </script>
    <script>
        func2('CCC');
    </script>
    <script>
        func2('DDD');
    </script>

    <script>
        function func3(x) {alert(x);}
        func3('EEE');
        func3('FFF');
    </script>
</body>
```

Sorry for my poor english.